# RESTFul Web Service with Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, rest

I am new to web services and I am trying to use RESTFul webservices. 
I am trying to pass parameter to RESTFul web server in Java from ajax.
Here is what I did

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="add">
        Add : <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <input type="submit" id="submitAdd">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function ()) {

$("#submitAdd").click(function() {
  var data = { name : $("#name").val() };
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Example/Rest/controller/return",
        data: data,
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(rdata) {

        }
  });
})
})
</script>
</html>
```

Controller.java

```
package com.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/controller")
public class Controller {

    @GET
    @Path("/return")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void add(String msg) {
        System.out.println("name "+ msg);
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>StockMonitor</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
<init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is the file structure

```
  Example 
     src
        ->com.controller
                        ->Controller.java
     WebContent
        ->META_INF
        ->WEB-INF
        ->index.html
```

The jars that I am using are -

all jars in `Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle` from
     https://jersey.java.net/download.html

When I enter this in the browser 
    http://localhost:8080/Example/Rest/controller/return
I get `HTTP Status 404 Error`.
I am unable to fix it . Can anyone please tell me whats the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 404 because `/Rest` is no where registered in any paths

1. Your context path is `/Example`
2. Then you controller is mapped to `/controller`

So You don't have a mapping to resolve `/Rest` since your controller is is bound to `/controller`URI path

Either remove the `/Rest` for your URL and update the servlet mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**OR**

Add the `/Rest` to your controller path mapping

```
@Path("/Rest/controller")
public class Controller {
```

Comment: Even after adding  `@Path("/Rest/Controller")` this error persists. Could there be any issue with the jars?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your  @Path("/return") annotation on your add(String msg) method. You are only needing to return from the path /Rest/controller and is the end point of your resource. @Path("/controller) annotation will search for the @GET in the resource class.

```
 package com.controller;

 import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
 import javax.ws.rs.POST;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

 @Path("/controller")
 @Consumes("application/json")
 public class Controller {

    @GET 
     public void add(String msg) {
         System.out.println("name "+ msg);
    } 
}
```